# Smart requirements searching

Tags: r

Let's say I have a lot of sequential functions. The result of each function is used for the next function in the sequence.

```
start <- "somevar"
a <- fun_a(start)
b <- fun_b(a)
c <- fun_c(b)
d <- fun_d(c)
e <- fun_e(d)
f <- fun_f(e)
```

Another way to look at this would be like:

```
start %>% fun_a %>% fun_b %>% fun_c %>% fun_d %>% fun_e %>% fun_f
```

What I would like to do is have something dynamic that understands when I pass it "d" for example, that it ought to run `fun_e` and `fun_f`.

Does R have some capabilities for this type of programming?

Bonus points if you know how one would refer to this concept from a computer scientists perspective.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [this](https://github.com/rbertolusso/intubate)

Comment: Are you looking for a kind of `make` (http://matt.might.net/articles/intro-to-make/)?

Comment: Could you provide a more specific example on how are the different sequential objects recognised? In addition to KotaMori's example with "class"es you could, also, use a simple `switch` depending on some "attr"ibute or an argument's possible values (via, e.g., `match.arg`)?

Comment: @JanvanderLaan yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for. A rules based system could work very well. Thanks for that.

Comment: @alexis_laz There are no rules, yet. I haven't built anything, I'm asking if something exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot alter behavior of functions by object names (at least in a natural manner).
But you can specify the function behavior based on the object classes.
This is a concept called function overloading. 
I think this is close to what you want to do.

In R, you can implement this by generic functions (See [Hadley's Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html)).

Here is a simple example.
The behavior of `MuFunc` changes by which class the passed object belongs to.
It also uses a recursive structure so that a function calls another function as in your example.

```
MyFunc <- function(x, ...) {
  UseMethod("MyFunc")
}

MyFunc.default <- function(x, ...) {
  print("running MyFunc.default")
  class(x) <- c("A", class(x))
  MyFunc(x)
}

MyFunc.A <- function(x, ...) {
  print("running MyFunc.A")
  class(x) <- c("B", class(x))
  MyFunc(x)
}

MyFunc.B <- function(x, ...) {
  print("running MyFunc.B")
  class(x) <- c("C", class(x))
  MyFunc(x)
}

MyFunc.C <- function(x, ...) {
  print("running MyFunc.C (Terminal Function)")
  class(x) <- c("D", class(x))
}

MyFunc(1)
##[1] "running MyFunc.default"
##[1] "running MyFunc.A"
##[1] "running MyFunc.B"
##[1] "running MyFunc.C (Terminal Function)"

x <- 1
class(x) <- "B"
MyFunc(x) 
##[1] "running MyFunc.B"
##[1] "running MyFunc.C (Terminal Function)"
```

Comment: I didn't even think of using s3. Nice.